# Why was override made to appear after a member declaration instead of same place as virtual?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm curious as to why the new C++11 keyword `override` is forced to appear after a method declaration in a manner consistent with `const` instead of `virtual`?

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    virtual void DoPolymorphicBehavior() = 0;
    ...
class SomeDerrivedClass : public SomeBaseClass {
    void DoPolymorphicBehavior() override;
    ...
```

Why in the world not allow it in the same exact position (and even instead of) `virtual`

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    virtual void DoPolymorphicBehavior() = 0;
    ...
class SomeDerrivedClass : public SomeBaseClass {
    override void DoPolymorphicBehavior();
    ...
```

This would have allowed me to do search & replaces in my source files for derived classes to trivially make use of the new keyword and thus get help from the compiler at finding errors.  However, because C++11 puts it in a different position syntactically, I would have to manually update literally several thousands of lines of source code in order to gain any benefit from the new compiler feature.

Surely there was a good reason behind this choice?

Comment: I would like to know the reasoning behind this, if there is any (there must be).  If there is a better place to ask, please point the direction...

Comment: I don't know who votes these language design questions for closing. If there is valid reason the OP is not aware of, it might be interresting to hear. If there is not and it was a throwing of dice, or decided by taste, well, that is an answer, too. And don't tell me nobody knows what the comittee really had in mind, there are enough people that know. +1 from me, hadn't thought about this alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The declaration specifier sequence that appears before the function name can contain an identifier (for example, the return type of the function). Imagine some existing code had a return type of `override`:

```
override foo();
```

Or even a variable called `override`:

```
int override;
```

Introducing a new keyword `override` would break any existing code that contained an identifier named `override` because keywords are reserved.

So instead of introducing a new keyword, they introduced a *contextual keyword*: `override` (and also `final`). A contextual keyword is identified as a keyword by its syntactic position. It is still fine to have identifiers called `override` and `final` in your program. If these identifiers appear after the argument list in a function declaration, they have a special meaning.

So the reason it is placed after the function arguments is because introducing new keywords will break old code and if the compiler sees `override` here they know exactly what it means, since no other identifier could appear here.

Comment: I would also add that putting it after the function make it clear that whats matters is the function and not the return type. They already had the problem with `const` and were forced to put it after the function not to be confused with the return type qualifier.

Comment: Whereas they have that issue with virtual?  Nah, I think this is an unfortunate result of unplanned evolution.  Were anyone designing C++ from the ground up (say, C#, Java, etc.), they would put the qualifiers before, because it's more in line with readability and how the human mind works.  Having const be a post-qualifier is, and will always be, an unfortunate choice / hang-over from C.  Making override and final follow this pattern is a necessary evil due to backwards compatibility, not some stroke of design-genius, imo.

Comment: @Mordachai Considering adjectives are put before a name in English, I agree it's more in line to put qualifiers before the functions to understand. IMHO, it's more a question of natural language than human mind. In my language - French -, adjectives are often pu after the noun, and doing it for qualifiers wouldn't bother me.
Well, since most programming languages use English, it's logical that it's a backwards compatibility matter more than a design evolution.

Comment: Ah, yes, culture-colored-glasses.  I would be less bothered if they'd been consistent.  But virtual comes before, const comes before or after many declarations except only after for member functions and i comes before e except after c and about another thousand exceptions.  But you're right, it's not 'human mind' level of universality, just English-speakers or other languages which tend to put adjectives/modifiers before the noun/subject.  :)

Answer (score 7):

It's not a keyword and that is the answer to your question as well.

It is an identifier with a special meaning in some contexts. If it were allowed to appear at the start of the declaration it could be ambiguous with, say, a user defined return type name.

Comment: @Mordachai A contextual keyword

Comment: So that is the reasoning: to avoid introducing a keyword, it was made a contextual keyword, which meant it had to appear after the method declaration?

Comment: @Mordachai: In a word, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Because `override` and `final` are not keywords, but symbols,
which can appear in user code.  (I.e. you can have a variable
`int override;`.)  They only take on their specific meaning in
limited contexts, and those contexts have to be chosen to
correspond to a context where a user defined symbol cannot
appear.  The desire was also to make this immediately clear; in
a case like:

```
override void DoSomething();
```

, `override` couldn't be a user symbol, because there's no
grammar production which could have a statement beginning with
a user defined symbol followed by `void`.  But the issue isn't
clear until the compiler encounters `void`, and if instead of
`void`, you have a user defined type, it's even more ambiguous.
On the other hand, after the parameter-declaration-clause of
a function, there context is clear, and the scanner of the
compiler knows immediately what to do.